# Construction of largest convex minorant of a sequence

Tags: convex-analysis

**Given a sequence $a_n$, construct the largest minorant $b_n$, i.e. $b_n \leq a_n$, that is convex.**

A natural candidate is
$$
b_n = \inf \left\{\frac{(r-n)a_l + (n-l)a_r}{r-l} \mid l \leq n < r\right\}
$$
assuming that this is well-defined.
This is clearly the case when the original sequence is bounded from below.

The values in the infimum are precisely the values of the lines joining $a_l$ and $a_r$ at $n$.
Any convex minorant should at least fulfill this condition.

**However, why is this regularization convex?**

Note that this question solves [Logarithmically Convex Minorant Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234785/logarithmically-convex-minorant-sequence).